# Sticky Footer not sticky to bottom of screen on larger devices - Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, footer, sticky-footer

I am trying to create a sticky footer that sticks to the bottom of the screen (not fixed), and moves down according to the amount of content added.

On larger screens the footer doesnt stick.

**View Here: http://www.bootply.com/VxVeDahZzG**

Comment: So its always there, no matter how far you scroll? like - http://www.cssplay.co.uk/layouts/basics2.html

Comment: @MatthewHammond - Nope, I just want it to stay at the bottom of the page. - Shouldnt be in view on scroll unless you are at the bottom of the page

Comment: But it already does? http://www.sonirepairs.com/

Comment: @TheOnlyError - Homepage yes, not the other pages, on the other pages it should be at the bottom of the page

Comment: It's really hard to mess around with inspect element to find out what your problem is. You could always just manually change the properties of the footer per page, but not a very elegant solution.

Comment: @RandomMath here you go: http://www.bootply.com/OtJZAWdEQg

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the size of your body to 100%.  Here is a nice site that helped me figure it out. http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Here is how he does it:

```
* {
margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important; 
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -155px; 
 }
.footer, .push {
    height: 155px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}
```

You also need to take your footer outside of your body for this to work.

Comment: I have already tried that and it didnt seem to make any difference

Comment: did you take your footer outside of your body?

Comment: Yes I have and no difference

Comment: @SariRahal you should not need to take the footer out of the body (any  html elements except head and body aren't children of html) in fact if you look at the HTML at the source, you'll see wrapper and footer, as actual siblings inside body